# Compile PHP - make test fails

Tags: php, compilation, debian

I am trying to build PHP 7.4.27 from source on a Debian 8 machine.

`configure` works fine (and I even tried `buildconf --force`).

`make` works fine.

But `make test` fails...

```
=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :   22
Exts tested     :   51
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests : 16021             12792
Tests skipped   : 3229 ( 20.2%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :   45 (  0.3%) (  0.4%)
Expected fail   :   35 (  0.2%) (  0.3%)
Tests passed    : 12712 ( 79.3%) ( 99.4%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :  561 seconds
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
EXPECTED FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Test open_basedir configuration [tests/security/open_basedir_linkinfo.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: BUG: open_basedir cannot delete symlink to prohibited file. See also
bugs 48111 and 52176.
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_008.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Discussion: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=120221184420957&w=2
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members - 2 [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_009.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Discussion: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=120221184420957&w=2
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Initial value of static var in method depends on the include time of the class definition [Zend/tests/method_static_var.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Maybe not a bug
DateTime::add() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
Bug #52480 (Incorrect difference using DateInterval) [ext/date/tests/bug52480.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52480
RFC: DateTime and Daylight Saving Time Transitions (zone type 3, bd2) [ext/date/tests/rfc-datetime_and_daylight_saving_time-type3-bd2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Still not quite right
RFC: DateTime and Daylight Saving Time Transitions (zone type 3, fs) [ext/date/tests/rfc-datetime_and_daylight_saving_time-type3-fs.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Still not quite right
Bug #42718 (unsafe_raw filter not applied when configured as default filter) [ext/filter/tests/bug42718.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW not applied when configured as default filter, even with flags
Bug #67296 (filter_input doesn't validate variables) [ext/filter/tests/bug49184.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #49184
Bug #67167: filter_var(null,FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN,FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE) returns null [ext/filter/tests/bug67167.02.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Requires php_zval_filter to not use convert_to_string for all filters.
via [ext/pdo_sqlite/tests/common.phpt]
        SQLite PDO Common: PDOStatement::getColumnMeta [ext/pdo_sqlite/tests/pdo_022.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: This feature is not yet finalized, no test makes sense
Phar: bug #69958: Segfault in Phar::convertToData on invalid file [ext/phar/tests/bug69958.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Still has memory leaks, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70005
updateTimestamp never called when session data is empty [ext/session/tests/bug71162.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Current session module is designed to write empty session always. In addition, current session module only supports SessionHandlerInterface only from PHP 7.0.
Bug #73529 session_decode() silently fails on wrong input [ext/session/tests/bug73529.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: session_decode() does not return proper status.
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Gettext basic test with en_US locale that should be on nearly every system [ext/gettext/tests/gettext_basic-enus.phpt]
Test if bindtextdomain() returns string id if no directory path is set(if directory path is 'null') [ext/gettext/tests/gettext_bindtextdomain-cwd.phpt]
Test dcgettext() functionality [ext/gettext/tests/gettext_dcgettext.phpt]
Test dgettext() functionality [ext/gettext/tests/gettext_dgettext.phpt]
Test if dngettext() returns the correct translations (optionally plural). [ext/gettext/tests/gettext_dngettext-plural.phpt]
Test ngettext() functionality [ext/gettext/tests/gettext_ngettext.phpt]
Bug #77020 (null pointer dereference in imap_mail) [ext/imap/tests/bug77020.phpt]
Bug #78014 (Preloaded classes may depend on non-preloaded classes due to unresolved consts) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78014.phpt]
Bug #78175 (Preloading segfaults at preload time and at runtime) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78175.phpt]
Bug #78175.2 (Preloading segfaults at preload time and at runtime) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78175_2.phpt]
Bug #78376 (Incorrect preloading of constant static properties) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78376.phpt]
Bug #78937.1 (Preloading unlinkable anonymous class can segfault) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78937_1.phpt]
Bug #78937.2 (Preloading unlinkable anonymous class can segfault) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78937_2.phpt]
Bug #78937.3 (Preloading unlinkable anonymous class can segfault) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78937_3.phpt]
Bug #78937.4 (Preloading unlinkable anonymous class can segfault) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78937_4.phpt]
Bug #78937.5 (Preloading unlinkable anonymous class can segfault) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78937_5.phpt]
Bug #78937.6 (Preloading unlinkable anonymous class can segfault) [ext/opcache/tests/bug78937_6.phpt]
Preloading basic test [ext/opcache/tests/preload_001.phpt]
Preloading prototypes [ext/opcache/tests/preload_002.phpt]
Preloading classes linked with traits [ext/opcache/tests/preload_003.phpt]
Preloading class with undefined class constant access [ext/opcache/tests/preload_004.phpt]
Handling of auto globals during preloading [ext/opcache/tests/preload_005.phpt]
Handling of errors during linking [ext/opcache/tests/preload_006.phpt]
Handling of includes that were not executed [ext/opcache/tests/preload_007.phpt]
Preloading of anonymous class [ext/opcache/tests/preload_008.phpt]
Preloading class using trait with undefined class constant access [ext/opcache/tests/preload_009.phpt]
Initializer of overwritten property should be resolved against the correct class [ext/opcache/tests/preload_010.phpt]
Argument/return types must be available for preloading [ext/opcache/tests/preload_011.phpt]
No autoloading during constant resolution [ext/opcache/tests/preload_012.phpt]
Nested function definition [ext/opcache/tests/preload_013.phpt]
Bug #79114 (Eval class during preload causes class to be only half available) [ext/opcache/tests/preload_bug79114.phpt]
Bug #78918: Class alias during preloading causes assertion failure [ext/opcache/tests/preload_class_alias.phpt]
Bug #78918.2: Class alias during preloading causes assertion failure [ext/opcache/tests/preload_class_alias_2.phpt]
Defining a dynamic function inside the preload script [ext/opcache/tests/preload_dynamic_function.phpt]
Bug #81353: Segfault with preloading and error handler using static variables [ext/opcache/tests/preload_error_handler.phpt]
Preloading: Loadable class checking (1) [ext/opcache/tests/preload_loadable_classes_1.phpt]
Preloading: Loadable class checking (2) [ext/opcache/tests/preload_loadable_classes_2.phpt]
Preloading: Loadable class checking (3) [ext/opcache/tests/preload_loadable_classes_3.phpt]
Bug #79548: Preloading segfault with inherited method using static variable [ext/opcache/tests/preload_static_var_inheritance.phpt]
Op array fixed up multiple times during preloading [ext/opcache/tests/preload_trait_multiple_fixup.phpt]
Preload trait with static variables in method [ext/opcache/tests/preload_trait_static.phpt]
Preload: Unresolved property type [ext/opcache/tests/preload_unresolved_prop_type.phpt]
int openssl_x509_checkpurpose ( mixed $x509cert , int $purpose [, array $cainfo = array() [, string $untrustedfile ]] ) function [ext/openssl/tests/openssl_x509_checkpurpose_basic.phpt]
Bug #71540 (NULL pointer dereference in xsl_ext_function_php()) [ext/xsl/tests/bug71540.phpt]
ziparchive::addEmptyDir error [ext/zip/tests/oo_addemptydir_error.phpt]
=====================================================================

You may have found a problem in PHP.
This report can be automatically sent to the PHP QA team [...]
```

What should I do? I also tried PHP 7.4.26 but many tests fail too.

I really need to update the PHP version on this server, but I don't feel confident about using a version that fails regression tests.

Any ideas?

Thank you all

Comment: Either skip tests, or see how it's done with debian/rules (line 341) http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.4/php7.4_7.4.26-1.debian.tar.xz ...........( Ideally you would build packages.deb with `$ apt-get -b source php7.4=7.4.26-1` .)

Comment: Thanks Knud! I'm tempted to do a make install without tests, because that's how I did it on another server and it is working fine, plus I don't think I magically did something that broke the PHP source code in my environment only oO I downloaded the file you sent me, thank you, I'll have a look and attempt to use it on my server to see the results :) thanks!